# Back Arrow and Angular Routing - Press Back Twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Angularv1.1.5

Site: http://tilsa.azurewebsites.net

I have a very simple route setup however when the user goes from the default/home route to the detail (pregunta) route and then clicks the back button nothing happens.  The 2nd/3rd time the back button is clicked the user returns (chrome) to the default/home route.  I'm not sure as to how or why this is happening.

```
$routeProvider.
when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/js/app/partial/index.html',
    controller: 'IndexCtrl'
})
.when('/pregunta/:id', {
    templateUrl: '/js/app/partial/detalle.html',
    controller: 'PreguntaDetalleCtrl'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

Here are the two relevant controllers.  I've removed some of the code that doesn't seem relevant (polling for new info/etc):

```
// load the index list of questions, the actual questions are loaded in parent scope

.controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', 'services', 'data', '$modal', 'navigation', 'timeFunctions', function ($scope, services, data, $modal, navigation, timeFunctions)
{
    $scope.noEncodeUrl = 'http://tilsa.azurewebsites.net/';

    $scope.url = encodeURIComponent($scope.noEncodeUrl);
    // controls the back arrow visibility to go back
    navigation.setReturn(false);

}])
.controller('PreguntaDetalleCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'services', 'navigation', 'graphService', 'stringFx', '$timeout', 'timeFunctions',  function ($scope, $routeParams, services, navigation, graphService, stringFx, $timeout, timeFunctions) {

    $scope.notas = [];

    $scope.comentario = '';

    navigation.setReturn(true);

    $scope.loadPregunta = function (id, loadComments)
    {
        services.preguntas.getDetalle(id).then(function (data)
        {
            $scope.safeApply(function ()
            {
                $scope.pregunta = data;
                graphService.setProp('title', $scope.pregunta.pregunta);
                $scope.noEncodeUrl = 'http://tilsa.azurewebsites.net/pregunta/' + id;

                $scope.url = encodeURIComponent($scope.noEncodeUrl);
                $scope.preguntaText = stringFx.removeAccent('¿'+$scope.pregunta.pregunta+'?');

            });

            if (loadComments)
            {

            $scope.commentTracker = {
                defaults: {             },
                skip: 0,
                take: 20
            };

            $scope.$on('$destroy', function (e)
            {
                $scope.stopPolling();
            });

            $scope.startPolling = function ()
            {

                // scrollTimeout will store the unique ID for the $setInterval instance
                return $scope.scrollTimeout = timeFunctions.$setInterval(poll, 10000, $scope);

                // Function called on interval with scope available
                function poll($scope)
                {
                    services.preguntas.getNotas($scope.pregunta.id, $scope.commentTracker, $scope.notas).then(function (data)
                    {


                        $scope.safeApply(function ()
                        {
                            for (i = 0, l = data.notas.length; i < l; i++)
                            {
                                $scope.notas.unshift(data.notas[i]);
                            }
                        });



                    });

                }
            }

            $scope.stopPolling = function ()
            {
                return timeFunctions.$clearInterval($scope.scrollTimeout);
            }

            $scope.startPolling();


            $scope.cargarAnteriores = function ()
            {
                //$scope.commentTracker.skip++;

                services.preguntas.getNotas($scope.pregunta.id, $scope.commentTracker, $scope.notas, true).then(function (data)
                {
                    $scope.safeApply(function ()
                    {
                        $scope.notas = $scope.notas.concat(data.notas);
                        $scope.masNotas = $scope.notas.length > 0;
                    });


                });

            }

            $scope.cargarAnteriores();
            }

        });

    }



    $scope.notaNueva = function () {
        //$scope.commentario;


        if ($scope.comentario.length < 3)
        {
            alert('Escribe algo mas, no seas tacano con tus palabras');
            return;
        }
        $scope.processing = true;

        services.preguntas.insertNota($scope.pregunta.id, $scope.comentario, $scope.notas, false).then(function (data)
        {

            $scope.comentario = '';
            $scope.processing = false;

            $scope.loadPregunta($scope.pregunta.id, false);

            services.preguntas.getNotas($scope.pregunta.id, $scope.commentTracker, $scope.notas).then(function (data)
            {

                $scope.safeApply(function ()
                {
                    for (i = 0, l = data.notas.length; i < l; i++)
                    {
                        $scope.notas.unshift(data.notas[i]);
                    }
                });

            });

        });
    }

    $scope.loadPregunta($routeParams.id, true)

    $scope.$on('updatedpregunta', function (event, obj)
    {
        $scope.loadPregunta(obj, false)

    });

}]);
```

Comment: could you show `PreguntaDetalleCtrl`? (and other parts relevant to your question?)

Comment: I didn't add them because they are a little heavy. I've added the index and pregunta controllers.

Comment: `navigation.setReturn();` what is that?

Comment: All it does is set a flag to true/false to show/hide a UI element (the back arrow on the details page).

Comment: @arturgrzesiak I've never had this issue before and am not doing anything with the $location service so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Angular side of your app is fine.

99% the problem is caused by some external library. For sure there is some problem with this script [kVEquaeit4R](http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yT/r/kVEquaeit4R.js) (it seens to be a facebook plugin), as it fails to load some resource (*404 error*): *The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.* and as a consequence a couple of further errors are generated (look at the console). And in turn it prevents the app from calling `window.location.hostname.replace` what actually is present in the `kVEquaeit4R` script.

So my suggestion is as follow: remove this fb plugin from your site and check if the `routing` works properly...

Comment: Thanks.. I am going to replace the social components with plain hyperlinks that link out to the prospective services.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well! Turned ut that artur grzesiak was right! I had a iframe on my page that had a binding for its src-attribute.

```
<iframe src="{{selected.url}}"></iframe>
```

Since the default value of $scope.selected.url was null the first thing that happened was that it was loading a url called null.

After some research I found that there was a special directive for the iframe:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{selected.url}}"></iframe>
```

This change solved my is

Comment: +1 for leading me into the mess of iframes and src. I found that I had to destroy and recreate the iframe so that my history was not touched.